# возможна ли графика в stringstream?

Tags: c++, qt

Имею функцию в `Qt`

```
void ob_panel::GetOb_PanelDate(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int minute, int seconds){

    std::stringstream output;

    output << day << ":" << month << ":" << year << "\n";
    output << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << seconds << "\n\n";
    output << "Höhe: Baro" << "\n";
    output << "DL: \t" << "\n";
    output << "GPS: " << "\n";
    output << "DVC recorder time" << "\n\n";
    output << "Video - Mitte" << "\n";
    output << "Ost: " << "\n";
    output << "Nord: " << "\n";
    output << "Grund " << std::endl;

    ui->pTE_Verbindung->setPlainText(output.str().c_str());
}
```

Хотел бы в поле `output << "GPS: " << "\n";` вывести графику как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, разве что псевдографическими символами :) Типа `■■■■■■■`... Только если цвет нужен - это уже не в строке дело, а в консоли...

Comment: @Harry можете привести пример кода с изменением цвета?

Comment: Вот [пример](http://mvblog.ru/archives/144/) как изменять цвет! Думаю разберешься.

Comment: Покопайтесь тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: @Harry даже если это не относиться к консоли?

Comment: Постараюсь пояснить еще раз. Строка - это просто набор символов. `stringstream` - это просто поток, работающий со строкой в памяти вместо, например, файла. Внутри него нет вообще понятия цвета. Что и как выводить цветом - зависит от устройства вывода. И в рамках стандартного C++ этот вопрос не решаем. Можно использовать соответствующий API, можно - ANSI-коды, если они поддерживаются. Но это уже не имеет никакого отношения к самой строке... У вас это определяется вызовом `ui->pTE_Verbindung->setPlainText(`. Сомневаюсь, что функция с названием `PlainText` знает что-то о цвете...